# Numpy: Retriving an array from an array of pointers

Tags: numpy, ctypes

I am writing a code, where I create an numpy array of pointers. They point to other arrays.

I can succesfully (no exception is generated) store a pointer inside one element of the array-of-pointers. But I cannot re-convert this pointer to a numpy array.

The problem specifically appears when pointers are stored in an numpy array of pointers. I can succesfully store and retrive an array when I store the pointer in a normal pyhon variable.

Note that I cannot just create a python list of pointers because of performances reasons.

#### this code works:

```
import numpy, ctypes
ic = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]],dtype=numpy.int32)
pointer = ic.__array_interface__['data'][0]
v = numpy.ctypeslib.as_array(ctypes.cast(pointer,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)),shape=(2,2))
print(v)
```

and `v` will return the initial array set in `ic`.

#### this code does not work:

```
import numpy, ctypes
ic = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]],dtype=numpy.int32)
pointers = numpy.zeros(5, dtype=ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
pointers[0] = ic.__array_interface__['data'][0]
numpy.ctypeslib.as_array(ctypes.cast(pointers[0],ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)),shape=(2,2))
```

The last line will give the following exception:

```
File "/opt/intel/intelpython3/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 484, in cast
return _cast(obj, obj, typ)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

**Question:** how do I store and retrive a numpy-array from/to a numpy-array of pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing the array returns a `np.int32` object, not a native Python `int`:

```
In [118]: type(pointer)
Out[118]: int
In [119]: type(pointers[0])
Out[119]: numpy.int32
```

Use `item` to extract the int:

```
In [120]: type(pointers[0].item())
Out[120]: int
```

You could also first convert the array to list

```
In [121]: type(pointers.tolist()[0])
Out[121]: int
```

`pointers` as you construct it is a `np.int32` dtype

```
In [123]: pointers = numpy.zeros(5, dtype=ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
In [124]: pointers.dtype
Out[124]: dtype('int32')
```

Alternatively make a object dtype array

```
In [125]: pointers = numpy.zeros(5, dtype=object)
In [126]: pointers[0] = pointer
In [127]: pointers
Out[127]: array([157379928, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object)
In [128]: type(pointers[0])
Out[128]: int
```